# How to call an action repeatedly with React and Easy Peasy

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, easy-peasy

I have a functional component which displays a list of item. The items are fetched via Ajax. I'm using **React** with **Easy Peasy**, a state management library.

```
const MyList = () => {

  const {fetchItems} = useStoreActions(actions => actions.myStore);
  const {items} = useStoreState(state => state.myStore);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems(); // Ok, fine, it works well here, done once.
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      Here are my Items
    </ul>
  )
}
```

This loads my items properly once. But I want to reload them repeatedly. So I found a custom hook :

```
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}
```

But when I do,

```
const MyList = () => {

  const {fetchItems} = useStoreActions(actions => actions.myStore);
  const {items} = useStoreState(state => state.myStore);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems(); // Ok, fine, it works well here, done once.
  }, []);

  useInterval(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, 2000);

  return (
    <ul>
      Here are my Items
    </ul>
  )
}
```

I get the following error :

```
  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at get (easy-peasy.esm.js:203)
    at Object.get$1 [as whats] (easy-peasy.esm.js:471)
    at eval (moderation.js:22)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at eval (moderation.js:21)
    at memoizerific (memoizerific.js:170)
    at Object.get$1 [as whats] (easy-peasy.esm.js:476)
    at eval (moderation.js:22)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

How to reload my items repeatedly?

Comment: Show how you calling this "hook" you found, you saying "after the useEffect, before the return", show whole code not just snippets. Refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think it would be easier to help if you supplied a CodeSandbox or some sort of an example showing more code and how you're using it.